# Ordinary field returned like zerofill field

Tags: mysql

I have a numeric field in a mySql database and I need to "concat" it with another numeric field but I need that the second field is returned as zerofill to preserve ordering of results.

I try to explain:

- First field = 2015; Second Field = 3 Concat_WS = 2015_3;
- First field = 2015; Second Field = 10 Concat_WS = 2015_10

So preserving right order
thanks to everyone

If I order the results 2015_10 will come before 2015_3

So I want to know if is there any way to obtain

- First field = 2015; Second Field = 3 Concat_WS = 2015_03;
- First field = 2015; Second Field = 10 Concat_WS = 2015_10

So preserving right order without changing field in zerofill.
Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lpad()`:

```
concat_ws('_', field1, lpad(field2, 2, '0'))
```

If these fields are original coming from dates, you should use `date_format()` instead:  `date_format(col, '%Y-%m')`.

Comment: Great! It's exactly what I need. (No, the fields are not dates. The first field is the year but the second is a number). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is right (fill with zero the Second Field), otherwise you can order two field separately as follow:

```
SELECT concat(FirstField, '_', SecondField)
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY FirstField, SecondField
```

without adding zero to fill the second field.